# each() if number of elements are present in each div, set class remove to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search result page. Each article there has an image, title, description and tags. I want that each article which has less than 6 tags, to add remove class from a div.

```
$('.searchTag-container').each(function(){
  cat = $('.searchResult__tag',this).children().length;
  if (cat < 6) { 
    console.log(cat);
    $(".share").addClass("remove");       
  }
});
```

When I do this the remove class adds to all of articles even if it has 6 or more tags.

```
<div class="row bottom">
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="searchResults">
        <div class="searchTag-container">
            <div class="searchResult__tag " data-number="0">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="1">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="2">
                <a href="# class="tag">Tag3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="3">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="4">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag5</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="5">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag6</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 share">
    <div class="social">
        <a class="btn-facebook"><img src="""></a>
        <a class="btn-twitter"><img src=""></a>
        <a class="btn-linkedin"><img src="""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide two rows structure together to let us know the relation between the `.searchTag-container` and the `.share` .. anyway you can try `$(this).closest(".row").find(".share").addClass("remove"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working ok, but the mistake is you are looping through `.searchTag-container`, which will iterate only once and you are checking `.searchResult__tag`'s length,

so in `.searchTag-container` there are 6 `.searchResult__tag` and each one has one children, so it gives length of all `.searchResult__tag`'s children combined so it becomes 6, and so variable `cat = 6` and it gives false when you check `cat < 6`.

So for solving it, you have to iterate through loop of each `.searchResult__tag` and check it's children length as i have done,

check below for working solution of your problem:

```js
$(function(){
$('.searchTag-container .searchResult__tag').each(function(){
  cat = $(this).children().length;
  if (cat < 6) { 
    console.log(cat);
    $(".share").addClass("remove");       
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row bottom">
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="searchResults">
        <div class="searchTag-container">
            <div class="searchResult__tag " data-number="0">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="1">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="2">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="3">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag4</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="4">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag5</a>
            </div>
            <div class="searchResult__tag" data-number="5">
                <a href="#" class="tag">Tag6</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 share">
    <div class="social">
        <a class="btn-facebook"><img src=""></a>
        <a class="btn-twitter"><img src=""></a>
        <a class="btn-linkedin"><img src="""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the Children with a specific class I would use `$(this).children('.searchResult__tag')` and get the length of that by `.length` as you did before

Answer (score 0):

you can try below script:

```
$('.searchTag-container').each(function(){
cat = parseInt($('.searchResult__tag',this).children().length);
if (cat < 6) {    
$(this).closest(".row").children(".share").addClass("remove");
 console.log(cat);
}
});
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4L7g8yj/1/)

Hope this will help you.